# Callback function / Run a function after adding a class with .addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a function on the selector that addClass was just ran on after addClass is completed.

This way made sense to me, but it doesn't seem to be working:

`$('.focused').addClass('fadeOutDown', function(){ $(this).remove(); });`

How can I run a function after I've ran the addClass function on the same selector?

Chaining runs it at the same time and I haven't tried a set-timeout, but that seem inefficient.

Comment: Class is added instantly after `$('.focused').addClass('fadeOutDown');`

Comment: addClass is _synchronous_, you don't need callback here.

Comment: @zerkms I know the class is added instantly. I'm trying to run a function after.

Comment: @gomangomango: put it on the next line. JS is evaluated line by line. The next line is evaluated right after the previous.

Comment: @undefined what does synchronous mean? Then how do I remove the same element that I added the class to after like I am trying to do?

Comment: try `$('.focused').addClass('fadeOutDown').remove();`

Comment: @rynhe nope, that does it all at the same time.

Comment: You have to work with any other event like click.

Comment: @gomangomango its working [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/eXaZUpu/1/edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do this way :

```
 $('.focused').addClass('fadeOutDown');

 setTimeout(function() {
     $('.focused').remove();
 }, 2000);

   // make sure you provide appropriate time i.e after you get the effect
```